Ubuntu 24.04 LTS text is not displaying
As you can see in the image, the texts are not displayed until I hover over it.


I tried this solution and it instantly fixed everything. I hope this will help you too.

Does this answer your question? Menu text items are not appearing

Ajay's link posted as a dupe.

yes it works thanks
